# What is the max size for MediaHistoryItem's ImageStream in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I was wondering what the max size for MediaHistoryItem's ImageStream is. It sets the image almost all the time, but sometimes, when it is a slightly larger image, it can not set it. So I was wondering if there is a limit to the ImageStream file size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to resize it to [358 x 358](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) pixels for the ***now playing*** tile, and 173x173 for all other tiles.

Larger images aren't supported. I would recommend you resize the image (in code), before you set the ImageStream property.

The byte size is limited to the [MediaHistoryItem.MaxImageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.mediahistoryitem.maximagesize%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Read the remarks at [MSDN about MediaHistoryItem.ImageStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.mediahistoryitem.imagestream%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot:) That´s really annoying, though, why would they limit the size? That limits the functionality :(

Comment: Why would it limit functionality? You're strongly encouraged to only use JPEG, and with JPEG it's never been a real problem in my experience.

Comment: The reason it is limited is probably because some JPEGs actually is bigger than the limit, so then you can´t use those pictures. I speak from experience, and that´s the reason I asked this question. But yeah, it works in pretty much all cases!